# How do i install GnuPG?

Tags: software-installation

i use ubuntu 16 but i can't seem to find ANY helpful information on installing this stealthy useful program. Can anyone write or link a step by step guide?

Answer (score 0):

It is installed by default. If you somehow managed to uninstall it, then install the `gnupg2` package again: `sudo apt install gnupg2`